# Sensors in ROS2 without driver

Tags: ros2, lidar

I got a new LiDAR from a seller who unfortunately does not provide any ROS2 support. Rather there is only a Point Cloud Visualiser .exe in Windows. I would like to use the LiDAR in my project of developing Autonomous Farming Vehicle but dont know how I can use this in ROS2 without any Package or Driver. Is it possible to use it somehow or develop a ROS2 supported package of the LiDAR??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an API or a device protocol specification available, then it would be possible to develop your own driver for the hardware.  This is how all existing drivers for ROS 2 have started.

Typically, people write a library that is independent of ROS, and then provide a ROS wrapper to make the sensor data available over ROS topics/services.

Example drivers that you may want to reference:

- https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/tree/humble-devel/velodyne_driver - Velodyne LIDAR driver, the lidar connects over ethernet and the driver uses PCAP to receive packets and expand them into `sensor_msgs/LaserScan`
- https://github.com/ros-drivers/ros2_ouster_drivers - Ouster lidar drivers
- https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node - Hokuyo lidar driver, wraps the official `urg_c` library

In the case that a manufacturer does not provide an API, then you will have to write the lower-level hardware driver yourself.  An example of this in the above list is the Velodyne driver, where the manufacturer provides a datasheet describing the packet format and the driver interprets the packets accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mjcaroll 
Can you please explain a little more about the libraries you wrote about. I mean I do know the wrapper approach but I thought the manufacturer provides the API.

Comment: I added a sentence about that in the answer.  Basically, in that case, it's up to you to do the driver implementation based on the material available. Typically this is a manufacturer-provided spec sheet, or in the rare case, reverse engineering the device protocol.